# Configuring PHP to Function with SMTP

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I have a register script that sends an email to who ever signs up.

```
        //// Set headers ////
        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "rn";
        $headers .= "Content-type: textrn";
        $headers .= "From: $from";
        /// Send the email now ////
        mail($email1, $subject, $message, $headers, '-f nleachman@stayontrack.net');
        //mail($email1, $subject, $message, $headers, '-f noreply@your-email.com');
        $db->commit();
        echo "Thanks for joining! Check your email in a few moments to activate your account so that you may log in. See you on the site!";
        $db = null;
        exit();
}
        catch(PDOException $e){
                $db->rollBack();
                echo $e->getMessage();
                $db = null;
                exit();
        }
```

Here is my SMTP server used for configuration:

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = nleachman@stayontrack.net

sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

When ever I try to run my log-in script I get this:

> **Thanks for joining! Check your email in a few moments to activate your account so that you may log in. See you on the site!**

My problem is that who ever signs - up never recieves the email. At first I thought that it may just be an impossible function on localhost. Then however, I saw some codes that worked for other people but gave me an error like...

> **Variable $From not set**

How could I configure my code so that it runs without errors?

Also, how could I configure the code to make sure who ever the email is sent to recieves it?

Comment: You need to use SMTP authentication (username and passwrd) in order to use gmail's smtp server. I would look into PHPmailer or some other php mail package that allows for smtp authentication.

Comment: I downloaded PHPMailer as kind of a last resort. I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For using SMTP within PHP, you should have a look at phpmailer. https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

easy to configure and does all the work for you.

Comment: How do I use PHPmailer?

Comment: @jacktherap just see the documentation. Theres basically a Copy&Paste Sample, where you just need to modify server & password.

Answer (score 0):

You're using mail() to send the email - I've had problems with this before not sending to certain domains like hotmail. I'd give PEAR mail a go - http://pear.php.net/package/Mail/redirected.